# Модуль 'csv' не имеет атрибута 'DictWriter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

тут появился такой вопрос. Вроде бы как в коде всё нормально, всё согласно документации. Но в итоге выходит такая вот проблема: "AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'DictWriter'"

```
import csv
with open('example.csv', 'w') as File:
    filednames =  ['brand', 'photo_file_name', 'carrying', 'passenger_seats_count']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(File, fieldnames= filednames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'brand':'Bugatti Veyron'})
    writer.writerow({'photo_file_name':'bugati.png'})
```

Comment: возможно вы где-то в коде переопределили переменную `csv` и затенили модуль  или назвали свой скрипт `csv.py` ?

Comment: @MaxU нет, это весь код. Там и стоит в скобках 'example.csv'

Comment: как вы назвали свой скрипт ?

Comment: @MaxU example_csv.py

Comment: Какой вывод `dir(csv)`?

Comment: похоже у вас в той директории из которой запускается скрипт лежит файл `csv.py` - и это не стандартный `csv`, а нечто другое

Comment: @MaxU, да у меня в той же директории лежит такой файл, его переименовать?

Comment: @MaxU, изменил имя файла в директории и программа запустилась. А вы не можете сказать по какой причине возникает такое?

Comment: `import csv` - импортирует сначала файлы из текущей директории, если не находит там, тогда смотрит в папке со стандартными либами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело вот в чем, если файл назван 'csv.py' или же есть файлы с таким названием в той же директории, то в этом случае будет выходить данная ошибка "AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'DictWriter'".
Всего что нужно - это переименовать скрипты в директории или тот скрипт за которым вы работаете. 
Это связано с тем, что цитирую @MaxU "import csv - импортирует сначала файлы из текущей директории, если не находит там, тогда смотрит в папке со стандартными либами"